# Email notification and mail server

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-server, g-suite, amazon-ses

I am building a web application with email notification just like Facebook, which will host in http://www.linode.com/. When a user A comment to a post, the poster will get an email notification from 'no-reply@mydomain.com' with the comment message written by user A. (Not spam)

I really like Google Apps but they have sending limits 2000 sending per day, that is not suit for my case becuz I cannot have sending limits. There will be many email notifications.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852

I also need company email accounts for team members use which I prefer Google Apps.

My web application will host in linode, I am considering "Amazon Simple Notification Service" for the email notification.

My questions are

1. Any other recommend email service provider suits my case for me?
2. Can I bind company email accounts(ex: jerry@mydomain.com) with Google Apps and bind no-reply@mydomain.com with other email service provider?

Comment: You work for a company and spell because as 'becuz'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use your corporate domain for sending these types of emails. Use a sub-domain or a completely different mail-specific domain. The reason is you don't want to damage the reputation of your real domain with automated emails. A lot of users mark these types of emails as spam. Also send from a different mail server/IP address.

I recommend *not* running the mail system yourself. There is a lot to managing your reputation, and doing tracking, and there are services that do it well. There are a lot of services, search the web for [transactional email delivery].

As to question #2, yes and no. No, you can't have mail delivered to a specific address go straight to different mail server than the rest of the domain, though you could forward to another server. Yes, you can *send* mail from any server you want, make sure SPF indicates the other server/service is allowed to send mail for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linode why don't you set up your own email server and then send your emails through smtp which is a process well documented in many languages.

http://library.linode.com/email/postfix

With a few modifications the backend can run on postgres if this is your db of choice.